# Codeception - How to address a field with non-unique name

Tags: php, css, codeception

I want to test a list of records with codeception. I have a form and have unique rows like this

```
<tr id="row1">
  <td class="description">
    <input name="description" type="text" value="some text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2">
  <td class="description">
    <input name="description" type="text" value="some more text">
  </td>
</tr>
```

so the name of the field is the same while the id of the row is not.
When I try to

```
$I->fillField("#row1 input[name='description']", "some other text");
```

it fails with

```
Field by name, label, CSS or XPath '#row1 input[name="description"]' was not found on page.
```

I believe the answer is just around the corner but I am struggling to find it.
Any hints or ideas?

Thanx,

m!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS selectors **td:nth-child(1)** or **td:nth-of-child(1)**.

Also beware (IRC) that PHPBrowser only can use fillField on fields contained inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use with xpath like:

```
$I->fillField("//*[@id='row1']//input","Input text here");
```

In case you really want to play with CSS, you can try with following code:

```
$I->fillField("#row1 input","Input text here");
```